# How to convert a *.txt file (copy/pasted variables) into a tabular format

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, format

I have a bunch of variables (roughly 80) which I copy+paste into my editor (get those variables from a different *.txt file). After this, it looks a bit messy like

```
ka15 1-2 tre15 3-4 hsha15 5
juso15 6
kl15 7-9 kkjs15 10
```

but I'd like to have it structured to get a better idea of what's going on inside the code. I also have to strip away the 15 from each variable. Ideally I would get something like

```
ka     1-2   tre   3-4   hsha   5
juso   6     kl    7-9   kkjs   10
```

Is there a clever way to achieve this? I am using **SAS Enterprise Guide Editor** and **VSCode** but couldn't find a way. For Example, when I find and replace the 15 I would wish I could replace it with a tab, but couldn't find that option in neither editors. Any ideas to get this automated or at least not do everything by hand?

Comment: Are you just talking about how to format code?

Comment: @Tom Well, basically yes. Though it's not about any specific code. I thought it would be good practice to format my code in the most accessible way, which means in this case, to put the variables in some sort of 'table' and not all over the place.

Comment: How many characters might each item have as a maximum?  I see 1-4, any more than that possible?

Comment: @Mark Yeah, possibly longer. The longest string so far had 9 characters after stripping the 15. But this is not fixed per se, though it's unlikely to have a variable which is longer than let's say 15 character.

Comment: Then my step 2 below would need to be expanded - it is doable but would be ugly-long.  It could be fairly easily generated programmatically though, it is a simple pattern.  The whole exercise is better suited for a script, but fun to do.

Comment: @Mark On my Linux machine I was playing around a bit in the bash using the column command and some regex, looks promising but isn't working so far. But I totally agree, a script would a nice thing to have.

Comment: @user190080 I have extensively reworked the regex's so they all work in vscode and used an extension that will run any number of regex find/replace pairs in sequence so that no other script solution is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hacky solution to your problem, if anyone finds a better solution, I'll delete mine, but here it goes `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`:

**1)** Copy all content of file(for example I copied yours twice):

```
ka15 1-2 tre15 3-4 hsha15 5
juso15 6
kl15 7-9 kkjs15 10
ka15 1-2 tre15 3-4 hsha15 5
juso15 6
kl15 7-9 kkjs15 10
```

**2)** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and replace all `15` with nothing (leave empty) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**3)** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and turn *Regular expressions* in search box. Now type `\s` to select whitespace and it should select one whitespace after every word. Now select all occurrences with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will delete spaces between the words and place one word on one line of code like so:

```
ka
1-2
tre
3-4
hsha
...
```

Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to remove multiple cursors.

**4)** Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> again and in search box type `$` sign. This wil select end of every line. Again, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to select all occurrences a press <kbd>Space</kbd> 5-8 times. Notice however that cursors are not properlly aligned. Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to remove multiple cursors.

[image: Space]

**5)** Place cursor a few spaces from a first word. Then, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to add multiple cursors below first one. Then, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to select all the whitespace to the end of every line and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete it. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> again to align all words in one line seperated by `n` spaces.

[image: Align all to one line]

**6)** Unfortunately, I couldn't find regex for the last part. Cursor should be placed after every 6th variable, but I solved it with by placing cursor next to every 7th word and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: Last part]

---

I usually don't type too much like this, but I liked the problem you had. It was more puzzle than a problem to me.

Comment: Nice puzzling, thanks (very nice illustration by the way)! I will test it any time soon and let you know how it works for me.

Comment: No problem. If it doesn't work, please link to me all the variables you need to copy and represent as table. In a meantime, I will try to find a better solution to 6th step.

Comment: Works! For automatization one could probably write a small (bash) script using all those regular expressions - I played around a bit but didn't come up with something useful...anyway, this works for now, thanks!

Comment: I'm really glad it did. Thank you for checking all this out :)

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with 3 regex's that will do what you want.  In order to run them all  sequentially you will need the [regreplace extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DomiR.regreplace) or similar.

This goes in your settings:

```
"regreplace.on-save": false,

"regreplace.commands": [
  {
    "name": "Transform Data to Table Format, step 1",
    "regexp": "([a-zA-Z]+|[\\d-]+)(15)?(\\s[\r\n]?)*", 
    "replace": "$1      \n",
    "priority": 1,      
  },
  {
    "name": "Transform Data to Table Format, step 2",
    "regexp": 
      "(([\\S-] {6})(.*))|(([\\S-]{2} {5})(.*))|(([\\S-]{3} {4})(.*))|(([\\S-]{4} {3})(.*))",
    "replace": "$2$5$8$11",
    "priority": 2,
  },
  {
    "name": "Transform Data to Table Format, step 3",
    "regexp": 
      "((.*)\n)((.*)\n)((.*)\n)((.*)\n)((.*)\n)((.*?)(\\s*\\n))",
    "replace": "$2$4$6$8$10$12\n",
    "priority": 3,
  }
],
```

It creates a rule for each of the three regex steps.  All three rules can be run sequentially by running the `regreplace.regreplace` command.  Here is a demo:

[image: demo of regreplace command running on OP's data]

The regex's are designed to look good with data items up to 4 characters long but could be easily modified for longer items.

In step 1, increase the number of spaces before the \n in the replace rule to something like 16 or so.

In step 2, you will have to sense the pattern of the regex groups  like `(([\\S-]{4} {3})(.*)` to modify them.  A 13 character long variable might require something like `(([\\S-]{13} {3})(.*)` as the last group and `([\\S-] {15})(.*))`as the first in the sequence, etc. modifying all the other groups in order.  Let me know if you need help with that.

Step 3 needs no modification unless you want to change how many data items appear on each line - right now there are 3 variables with their data on each line hence 6 groups in that regex.

It does not matter how many data-value pairs are in any row prior to running the command.

[Two items of caution:  There **should not be any empty lines before the start of the data**, although if necessary you could a regex as the first rule to remove empty lines.  Empty lines within the data or at the end are not a problem.

Secondly, the extension cannot be run on selected text only so you will have to place your data at the top of an empty file to convert it and then copy it elsewhere if you wish.]

There is also the [replace rules extension](https://github.com/bhughes339/vscode-replacerules) which works like regreplace but will according to the docs run on a selection only but it didn't work for me here for some unknown reason.  It does have a nicer interface though - all regex's could go into a single rule which could then be independently run.

Comment: Thanks Mark (also for the regex page, quite handy), that looks pretty nice too, gonna check it out!

Comment: This looks elegant. I'll check it out later and let you know how it works for me - really appreciate your help! Since I am rather inexperienced when it comes to regex I might need some time to get through the syntax